# Is AutoMapper's (4.2+) Profile part of Logic or Infrastructure?

Tags: c#, wcf, domain-driven-design, automapper, ninject

I have WCF Service, that acts like ORM. I need a mapper to map Entities to Dtos. Having in mind **Separation of concerns**, **SOLID** and **DDD**, I was wondering where should AutoMapper configuration and Profiles go? My project structure looks like that:

Data (EF) -> Logic -> WCF Services / WCF Contracts -> WindowsService (host)

I followed rules from [github](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Dependency-injection.md), I created a Ninject module:

```
public class AutoMapperModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IValueResolver<SourceEntity, DestModel, bool>>().To<MyResolver>();

        var mapperConfiguration = CreateConfiguration();
        Bind<MapperConfiguration>().ToConstant(mapperConfiguration).InSingletonScope();

        // This teaches Ninject how to create automapper instances say if for instance
        // MyResolver has a constructor with a parameter that needs to be injected
        Bind<IMapper>().ToMethod(ctx =>
             new Mapper(mapperConfiguration, type => ctx.Kernel.Get(type)));
    }

    private MapperConfiguration CreateConfiguration()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfiles(new SampleProfile());
        });

        return config;
    }
}

public class SampleProfile : Profile
{
    public SomeProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Foo, FooDto>();
    }
}
```

I always create a Ninject module at the entrance of the executable program, so in Windows Service. But I'm a little confused, cause my Windows Service project doesn't have "Data" reference (with Entities). So I have a few questions:

1. Should I add reference to "Data" project in WindowsService (host) and create a AutoMapper Profile class in WindowsService?
2. Should I define AutoMapper Profile class in Logic class (which knows about Dtos and Entities) and then reference Logic in WindowsService where module will be initialized?
3. Should I put AutoMapper Profile somewhere else?

Thanks!

Comment: Of course it's infrastructure. Any 3rd part libraries that do a very specific part are infrastructure, including but not limited: ORM, Database providers, UI (MVC, WebForms), Endpoints (WCF, WebAPI), Authentication, Xslt processors, service/message bus (implementations), local and distributed caches, Swagger and of course AutoMapper. Also please keep in mind, IoC containers (since you mention using ninject modues) are **infrastructure** too, since they are replaceable and not an essential part of your domain/business logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with Java, with this structure

> Data (EF) -> Logic -> WCF Services / WCF Contracts -> WindowsService (host)

I think as a set of different packages/projects. Every package/project then is (in my interpretation):

- Data (EF): mapping of Entities to Persistence, knows how to get an Entity and translate it to a Dto (here I would put the configuration/logic that tells AutoMapper how to transform the objects)
- Logic: where lies the logic of your Domain, that should be the Core of the architecture, it should (MUST, I would say) be unaware of other packages/projects
- WCF Services / WCF Contracts: a set of interfaces that expose functionalities
- WindowsService (host): the implementation of the interfaces, hence where the glue code between the other packages/projects lies. For example, here I would put the profiles of AutoMapper.

The **WindowsService (host)** is a kind of infrastructure layer, where all the things are put together. Here you need to reference every package/project you're going to use (Data, Logic, WCF Services / WCF Contracts).

Comment: hmm.. You said about `Data` - "here I would put the configuration/logic that tells AutoMapper how to transform the objects". Then about WindowsService (host) you said: "here I would put the profiles of AutoMapper.". So.. where?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not used to AutoMapper. I've thought that configuration and profiles are separated and live indipendent from each other (bad interpretation of what you've written). Given that this is not true, even if you can choose between `data` and `WindowsService (host)`, I would suggest the second. In this way the infrastructure code (the glue code) stays in one well defined location.

Answer (score 1):

Put the profile in **Logic** as this is the furthest point upstream you could put it, that is Logic has the two sides of mappings (Entities and Dtos).  If you wanted to keep the Logic as aesthetically clean as @Luca suggests then you'd probably want to think about moving your Dtos into your WCF layer (along with Profiles).

Your windows service surely already has a reference to this Logic.

This way other projects, a web app perhaps, that might use this Logic would have the profile to use too.